# Unmarshalling JSON string with Golang

Tags: go

I have the following json string

{"x":{"l.a":"test"}}

```
type Object struct {
    Foo  map[string]map[string]string `json:"l.a"`
    }
     var obj Object
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &obj)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("jsonObj", obj)
```

but get empty any idea how can i get the string "test"

Comment: You're defining `Foo` to look into the `l.a` property but that property is not present in the root object. Maybe your intention is to have `json:"x"` as the tag.  Also, `map[string]map[string]string` is redundant, `Object` acts like the root object so you would need just `map[string]string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a struct to unmarshall your json

```golang
type My_struct struct {
    X struct {
        LA string `json:"l.a"`
    } `json:"x"`
}

func main() {
    my_json := `{"x":{"l.a":"test"}}`
    var obj My_struct
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(my_json), &obj)
    fmt.Println(obj.X.LA)
}
```

here you are creating a struct and then unmarshalling your json string to its object, so when you do `obj.X.LA` you will get the string

Answer (score 2):

With your code `Unmarshal` is looking for `l.a` at the top level in the JSON (and it's not there - `x` is).

There are a number of ways you can fix this, the best is going to depend upon your end goal; here are a couple of them ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HLWWpCUWXCQ))

```golang
const jsonTest = `{"x":{"l.a":"test"}}`

type Object struct {
    Foo map[string]string `json:"x"`
}

func main() {
    var obj Object
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonTest), &obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("jsonObj", obj)

    var full map[string]map[string]string
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonTest), &full)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("jsonObj2", full)

}
```

(Got a phone call while entering this and see @DavidLilue has provided a similar comment but may as well post this).